# Replacing old track lighting

Tags: lighting, ceiling

I took down some OLD track lighting and want to put in remodeling cans. This lighting is on a three way switch. When i went to wire in the new cans i noticed there are two sets of wires, each having a ground, black, white and red. How do i go about wiring this to the can?

We tried capping off the two red, then putting white/white, black/black and ground/ground.. blows the circuit.

Comment: The old track lighting should have been wires to just three wires, white, ground and (likely) black. The new can lights should be wired exactly the same. If you took apart other splices you need to put them back exactly how they were.

Comment: Could possibly be a MWBC track.

Answer (score 0):

The red is known as the traveler and capping it would have worked if it was a single pole solution but in a 3 way please see the diagram below to see the wiring pattern for a 3 way also single pole or timer if that should arise.[image]

Comment: It seems as if he has two 3-wire cables at the light.